# MSAL SsoSilent throws exception interaction_required error in Firefox

Tags: firefox, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

I have two angular apps and I have implemented sso for both my apps to share the authentication state between them. The issue is in firefox due to enhanced protection is on in firefox.

Is there any workaround to handle this scenario to use ssosilent if enhanced protection is on in any browser?